# Fetch complete objects including children using Golang and Gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I'm using Gorm and Golang to fetch data from my database. Is it possible to make Gorm fetch also the objects children (foreign keys)?

**Database tables**

```
users
+----+---------+------------+
| id | name    | country_id |
+----+---------+------------+
|  1 | Adam    |          1 |
|  2 | Bertil  |          1 |
|  3 | Charlie |          2 |
+----+---------+------------+

countries
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Sweden |
|  2 | Norway |
+----+--------+
```

**Models**

```
type User struct {
    Id        int64   `json:"-"`
    Name      string  `json:"name"`
    CountryId int64   `json:"-"`
    Country   Country `json:"country"`
}

type Country struct {
    Id   int64  `json:"-"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

**Code to fetch all users**

```
var users []User
DB.Find(&users) // Question: How should this be modified to automatically fetch the Country?
```

**Actual result**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Adam",
        "country" : {
            "name": "",
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

**Desired result**

```
[
    {
        "name": "Adam",
        "country" : {
            "name": "Sweden",
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

Thanks a lot for you input!

/Klarre

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is possible, it's called [Preloading](https://gorm.io/docs/preload.html).

```golang
users := make([]User,0)
DB.Preload("Country").Find(&users)
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for. :)